# User in Windows 7 unable to modify text file

Tags: windows, file, security, permission-denied

I have a software that do read and append a txt file that is located on the C:\ drive. It works perfect on Windows XP environment when a normal user in users group (not administrators) login and run the software.

However when using Windows 7 and login as a normal user in users group, I'm getting access denied even though I have modified the security of the text file to full access for that user and users group.

I have also change the ownership of the file to the users group and to the user itself.

If I change the path to the D:\ drive, there is no issue at all, but I need this to work on the C:\ drive.

I even tried changing ownership of the C:\ drive and adding write permissions as well and it didn't work.
I can't put the user into administrators group.

Thank you for your input.

Comment: IIRC, the default permissions on the root of the system drive changed in Windows Vista.  The solution is to put the file in a more appropriate location.

Answer (score 1):

Try opening the software as administrator and then open the txt file through the software. BTW where is it exactly located the txt file? (Sorry I cant comment , I havent 50 rep)

Comment: I did login with administrator and I can alter the text file. Harry Johnston comment above is correct that it seems like the permission has changed after vista.